# Can't Set Headers After They Are Sent in nodejs and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am submitting login form and checking whether the username or password is correct but here I am stuck in given error please help me out to solve this error. Thanks

```
app.post('/login', function(request, response) {

  var username = request.body.username;
  var password = request.body.password;
  if (username && password) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
      console.log(results);
      if (results.length > 0) {
        request.session.loggedin = true;
        request.session.username = username;
        // request.session.w_id = us;
        response.redirect('/');
        next();
      } else {
        response.render('login', {layout: 'login',error:'Invalid Username Or Password'});
      }         
      response.end();
    });
  } else {
    response.render('login', {layout: 'login',error:'Please Enter Username And Password'});
    response.end();
  }
});
```

**Error**

```
throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\Node Projects\uni_project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:775:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (D:\Node Projects\uni_project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:603:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\Node Projects\uni_project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:149:14)
    at done (D:\Node Projects\uni_project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:10)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (D:\Node Projects\uni_project\node_modules\express-handlebars\lib\utils.js:26:13)
    at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
```

Comment: `response.end()` of you first `if` might be conflicting with response from your redirected page `response.redirect('/')`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this block

```
  if (results.length > 0) {
    request.session.loggedin = true;
    request.session.username = username;
    // request.session.w_id = us;
    response.redirect('/');
    next();
  } else {
    response.render('login', {layout: 'login',error:'Invalid Username Or Password'});
  }         
  response.end();
```

Once you are inside the if loop, and it's successful you've redirected and your response has ended. But Javascript will continue to the next line outside the if loop to `response.end()` and that's why you get the error stated. You also cannot invoke `next()` because this implies that the request needs further processing where infact your request is fulfilled when you invoke `response.end()` or `response.redirect`

The correct one would be -

```
app.post('/login', function(request, response, next) {

 var username = request.body.username;
 var password = request.body.password;
 if (username && password) {
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?',[username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
    console.log(results);
   if (results.length > 0) {
    request.session.loggedin = true;
    request.session.username = username;
    // request.session.w_id = us;
    response.redirect('/');
  } else {
    response.render('login', {layout: 'login',error:'Invalid Username Or Password'});
  }         

} 
else {
response.render('login', {layout: 'login',error:'Please Enter Username And Password'});

}
 });
```